# Disable alt functionality but not alt combined with other keyboards functionality

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-events, onkeydown

I want to disable the alt key, so I added `PreviewKeyDown` function to my window and this is how it looks:

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (ModifierKeys.Alt == Keyboard.Modifiers)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

It does disable the alt functionality but **I dont want** to disable alt+other key functionality such as Alt+F4 or any other combinations that uses alt (I dont what are the other combinations that uses alt beside Alt+F4, if there any)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it better to do a check for the known keyboard events and allow these and denie all others? because denieing Alt key with PreviewKeyDown it will not work because every time you press the alt key it will be captured and handled before you can do anything else with it

Comment: I dont think you are right. this works for me >  (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt && !(e.SystemKey == Key.F4)), disable alt functionality but not alt+f4 - if I need to wrtie all the combinations it might be ok too but I dont know all the possible combinations